# requestAnimationFrame processing sequence

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

If I have the following code:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(animation1); //animation1 takes more than 16.67ms, misses the frame.
window.requestAnimationFrame(animation2); //animation2 takes 1ms to execute
```

Assuming `animation1` and `animation2` are simple color change animations, does it mean that `animation2` would appear on the screen before `animation1`?

Or are the calls to `requestAnimationFrame` stacked on the browser queue, where the subsequent call will only execute when the previous call finishes?

Comment: What do you mean by "misses the frame"?

Comment: James, the browser is doing a repaint at 60fps(on a 60hz screen). That's 1frame/16ms, if my callback takes more than 16ms it would miss being on that frame.
Ingrams, I am aware tat the animation function will be called once, that's not the question. The question is about which of those two simple animations would show first given the execution duration i specified in the question.

Comment: The browser _attempts_ to do a repaint at 60fps - this bit is covered towards the end of my answer.  I linked to a slightly different part of the spec in my answer, but see [the note below step 3](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#processing-model-8:top-level-browsing-context) here - it can throttle the callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`animation1` will always run to completion before `animation2` is called, but if either of them is taking too long, the browser might not call either of them for a frame or two.

---

[The specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#animation-frames) for `requestAnimationFrame` says:

> When the requestAnimationFrame() method is called, the user agent must run the following steps:
>   ...
>
> 3. Append the method's argument to document's list of animation frame callbacks, associated with document's animation frame callback identifier's current value.

and:

> When the user agent is to run the animation frame callbacks for a Document doc with a timestamp now, it must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Let callbacks be a list of the entries in doc's list of animation frame callbacks, in the order in which they were added to the list.

So we can see that by running:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(animation1);
window.requestAnimationFrame(animation2);
```

You are queueing up `animation1` and `animation2` to be called the next time *"the user agent is to run the animation frame callbacks"*.

That time [is specified](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#processing-model-8:run-the-animation-frame-callbacks) as part of the main event loop:

> 9. For each fully active Document in docs, run the animation frame callbacks for that Document, passing in now as the timestamp.

However before that, it specifies:

> 3. If there is a top-level browsing context B that the user agent believes would not benefit from having its rendering updated at this time, then remove from docs all Document objects whose browsing context's top-level browsing context is B.

That means if your callbacks are taking too long, it may decide to drop frames and not run them.  However, since all requested frames are executed one after the other in step 9, you should *always* see the result of `animation1` before `animation2`, but the browser *may* decide to drop the entire document from it's rendering loop and not call *either* method in the queue until a subsequent iteration through the event loop.